# How to use DBIO.sequence and avoid StackOverflowError

Tags: slick, slick-3.0

I am a Slick beginner, just experimenting with Slick 3.0 RC1. In my first project I'd like to import data from a text file to various tables. The whole import should happen in sequence as the data are in the file within one transaction.

I tried to create an Iterator of the actions and wrap them in a DBO.sequence.

The problem is that when the number of rows is big then the import fails with a StackOverflowError. Obviously I have misunderstood how to use Slick to do what I want to do. Is there a better way how to chain a large number into one transaction?

Here a simplified version of my code, where instead of reading the data from a file, I simply "import" the numbers from a Range. The even ones to the table XS, the odd ones to the table YS.

```scala
val db = Database.forConfig("h2mem1")

try {

  class Xs(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Long, String)](tag, "XS") {
    def id = column[Long]("ID", O.PrimaryKey)
    def name = column[String]("NAME")
    override def * : ProvenShape[(Long, String)] = (id, name)
  }

  class Ys(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Long, String)](tag, "YS") {
    def id = column[Long]("ID", O.PrimaryKey)
    def name = column[String]("NAME")
    override def * : ProvenShape[(Long, String)] = (id, name)
  }

  val xs = TableQuery[Xs]
  val ys = TableQuery[Ys]


  val setupAction = DBIO.seq((xs.schema ++ ys.schema).create)

  val importAction = DBIO.sequence((1L to 100000L).iterator.map { x =>
    if (x % 2 == 0) {
      xs +=(x, x.toString)
    } else {
      ys +=(x, x.toString)
    }
  })

  val f = db.run((setupAction andThen importAction))

  Await.result(f, Duration.Inf)

} finally {
  db.close
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the not very efficient implementation in the RC1 version of Slick. The implementation has been improved as seen in the issue thread [here](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1113).

In the Slick 3 RC 3 the problem is solved :)